# How Flask-Bootstrap works?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, templates, flask, flask-bootstrap

I'm learning Flask web development, and the tutorial I'm following introduces an extension called **Flask-Bootstrap**. To use this extension, you must initialize it first, like this:

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
# ...
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

Weirdly enough to me, the variable `bootstrap` is not used in the rest of my module. However, if I comment out this line, a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound` exception will be raised. Also, the templates used start with this line:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
```

But I don't have a directory named `/bootstrap` under `/templates`!

I want to know what's going on:

1. What does the `bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)` line do?
2. Where does `bootstrap/base.html` reside?

Comment: Read about public source code if you want learn more about how it works. For Bootstrap : https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/__init__.py

Comment: I've already seen the question you linked to, but I also want to inspect the content of `bootstrap/base.html`, and that question doesn't provide its specific location. Furthermore, I'm willing to hear how can jinja2 find it.

Comment: Flask-boostrap is a blueprint - a sort of sub-app for a Flask app. When you register a blueprint, as in `bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)`, it registers in the app some rules which say to Flask where the blueprint's own `static` and `template` folders are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Other answers have told you**

> the bootstrap = Bootstrap(app) line "init the extension on the app".
>
> The bootstrap/base.html resides in the Flask-Bootstrap package.

To understand this, you must know something about "Flask's template searchpath"

1. application's template folder
2. Blueprint's template folder

**So the Flask-Bootstrap actually register a blueprint to your app**：

```
class Bootstrap(object):
    def __init__(self, app=None):
        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app):
        blueprint = Blueprint(
            'bootstrap',
            __name__,
            template_folder='templates',
            static_folder='static',
            static_url_path=app.static_url_path + '/bootstrap',
            subdomain=app.config['BOOTSTRAP_LOCAL_SUBDOMAIN'])

        app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

You can see it clearly by set EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING'] = True
```

then

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

when you access the page:

```
[2018-07-12 15:28:58,659] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template "user.html":
1: trying loader of application "hello"
   class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
   encoding: 'utf-8'
   followlinks: False
   searchpath:
     - /root/learn/python-lab/Flask/flasky/templates
   -> found ('/root/learn/python-lab/Flask/flasky/templates/user.html')
2: trying loader of blueprint "bootstrap" (flask_bootstrap)
   class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
   encoding: 'utf-8'
   followlinks: False
   searchpath:
     - /root/learn/python-lab/Flask/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates
   -> no match
################################################################# Note here #######
[2018-07-12 15:28:58,677] INFO in debughelpers: Locating template "bootstrap/base.html":
1: trying loader of application "hello"
   class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
   encoding: 'utf-8'
   followlinks: False
   searchpath:
     - /root/learn/python-lab/Flask/flasky/templates
   -> no match  ### in app path not found
2: trying loader of blueprint "bootstrap" (flask_bootstrap)
   class: jinja2.loaders.FileSystemLoader
   encoding: 'utf-8'
   followlinks: False
   searchpath:
     - /root/learn/python-lab/Flask/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates
   ## in blueprint path found the bootstrap/base.html
   -> found ('/root/learn/python-lab/Flask/flasky/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html')
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2018 15:28:58] "GET /user/Yao HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

- Addition，The Blueprint template folder is added to the search path of templates but with a lower priority than the actual application’s template folder,  see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#templates

Answer (score 2):

As @davidism said in his comment, the `bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)` line "installs the extension on the app". The mechanism behind such installation is beyond the scope of this answer.

The `bootstrap/base.html` resides in the Flask-Bootstrap package. For example, on my machine it's absolute path is:

```
/Users/sunqingyao/Documents/Projects/flasky/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html
```

Here is its content:

```
{% block doc -%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{% block html_attribs %}{% endblock html_attribs %}>
{%- block html %}
  <head>
    {%- block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}{{title|default}}{% endblock title %}</title>

    {%- block metas %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {%- endblock metas %}

    {%- block styles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{bootstrap_find_resource('css/bootstrap.css', cdn='bootstrap')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    {%- endblock styles %}
    {%- endblock head %}
  </head>
  <body{% block body_attribs %}{% endblock body_attribs %}>
    {% block body -%}
    {% block navbar %}
    {%- endblock navbar %}
    {% block content -%}
    {%- endblock content %}

    {% block scripts %}
    <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('jquery.js', cdn='jquery')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{bootstrap_find_resource('js/bootstrap.js', cdn='bootstrap')}}"></script>
    {%- endblock scripts %}
    {%- endblock body %}
  </body>
{%- endblock html %}
</html>
{% endblock doc -%}
```

<sub>The answer to "how can Jinja2 find `base.html`" would be added as soon as I find the relevant part in the document.</sub>